# Python Process spawning within for loop

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I was trying to parallelize one of our more time consuming tasks, but couldn't get it working, and can't really figure out why.

My code:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg
import os
from multiprocessing import Queue
from multiprocessing import Process
from typing import Tuple
    
num_cpu = os.cpu_count()
arr_1 = np.random.random((20000, 1000))
arr_2 = np.random.random((20000, 1000))
   
def cosine_similarity( a: np.ndarray, b: np.ndarray):
    assert len(a) == len(b)
    len_a = linalg.norm(a)
    len_b = linalg.norm(b)
    # Check if one vector is all zeros. Possible, not probable
    if len_a == 0 or len_b == 0:
        return 0
    return a.dot(b) / (len_a * len_b)

def cosine_distance(a: np.ndarray, b: np.ndarray):
    assert len(a) == len(b)
    return 1 - cosine_similarity(a, b)

def run_task(start: int, end: int, queue_out: Queue):
    print("Called with " + str(start) + " to " + str(end))
    if end > len(arr_1):
        end = len(arr_1)
    for i in range(start, end):
        min_dist = 2.0
        labeled_data = arr_1[i]
        for unlabeled_data in arr_2:
            min_dist = min(min_dist, cosine_distance(labeled_data, unlabeled_data))

        queue_out.put((i, min_dist))

step = len(arr_1) // num_cpu

t_s = []
queue = Queue()
for i in range(0, len(arr_1), step):
    print("Calling with " + str(i) + " to " + str(i + step))
    p = Process(target=run_task, args=(i, i + step, queue))
    p.start()
    t_s.append(p)

for p in t_s:
    p.join()
```

When I call `queue.qsize()`, its 0. The code also basically finishes instantly, and I get only the "Calling with..." output, but not the "Called with"

If I manually call `run_task(0, 1000, queue)`, it runs for several minutes (about 3), and `queue.qsize()` is 1000.

When I look at `t_s`, it gives me 20 lines of `<Process name='Process-21' pid=17948 parent=4044 stopped exitcode=1>,` (with different process names and pid's).

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit:

tried with Pool.map:

```
def run_task(index):
    print("Called index " + str(index))
    min_dist = 2.0
    labeled_data = arr_1[index]
    for unlabeled_data in arr_2:
        min_dist = min(min_dist, cosine_distance(labeled_data, unlabeled_data))

    (index, min_dist)

a = 0
with Pool(processes=num_cpu) as pool:
    a = pool.imap(run_task, range(len(arr_1)))

for i in a:
    print(f"showing the result as it is ready {i}")
```

Same behaviour, nothing seems to be called

Comment: Instead of manual fiddling with Process objects, I'd recommend looking at Pool.map, Pool.imap and Pool.imap_unordered instead.

Comment: Updated the code with Pool.map, still does absolutely nothing

Comment: Now that you have the `Pool` and given it the task, next call `pool.close(); pool.join()` inside the `with` statement to make it actually run.

Comment: I tried something else, used a premade code example, it worked in a python file, not in jupyter. I am testing it as a py file right now, but it might be that I was looking in the wrong place

Answer (score 0):

Okay, turns out it had something to do with my imports for whatever reason. After I changed it from `Process` to `multiprocessing.Process`, it worked, so I guess there was some namespace masking happening.